# ASP.net based open source support ticket system

Tags: asp.net

I am in search of ASP.net based open source support ticket system. are there any suggestions?

Comment: @RubensFarias: Yes it is, in fact I found this question through Google. Don't be pedantic.

Comment: @SergioTapia, SO is about programming problems, not about software installation. I understand your point, but this question could be better answered on other trilogy sites. I also deleted my 3 years old comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. [Bugtracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html)
2. [BugNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bugnet/)

I prefer BugNet over others for a number of reasons. It is regularly updated and has quite a good number of followers.

Comment: Neither are actually help desk/support ticket applications. They're primarily for issue and bug tracking. While "they'll do" for other purposes, they're missing out on a lot based on the angle they tackle the issue from.

Answer (score 8):

[https://github.com/NullDesk/TicketDesk/](https://github.com/NullDesk/TicketDesk)

TicketDesk is an issue tracking system for IT Help Desks.

TicketDesk is efficient and designed to do only one thing, facilitate communications between help desk staff and end users. The overriding design goal is to be as simple and frictionless for both users and help desk staff as is possible.

TicketDesk 2 is an ASP.NET MVC web application written in C# targeting the .NET 4.5 framework. It includes a simple database with support for SQL Server 2005, 2008, or 2012 (including express and localdb editions). It can leverage SQL server for membership and role based security or integrate with windows authentication and Active Directory groups.

Comment: I really liked this package in the online demos but cannot for the life of me get this to run locally with a 2008r2 SQL Server DB on a remote server in my network.  I keep getting the following error: "The specified named connection is either not found in the configuration, not intended to be used with the EntityClient provider, or not valid.".  I'm about to give up and look for another package.

Comment: I fixed this in mine but checking that every connection string was pointing at the new location of the database.

Answer (score 6):

http://slickticket.codeplex.com

Comment: its windows form.. not asp.net app

Answer (score 6):

Jitbit (disclaimer: the company I work for) offers a [ticketing system](http://www.jitbit.com/web-helpdesk/) that is ASP.NET based (MVC) with "full sources" license available. It's not free though. But we do have a free trial version that has no "time limit" - you can run it as long as you want.