# Free C# / ASP.NET E-Mail Ticket Support System for postgresql?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking for an open source ticket system that I can use with our postgresql database (npgsql or dotconnect).

I have found that link, but all posted systems need MS SQL:
[ASP.net based open source support ticket system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748247/asp-net-based-open-source-support-ticket-system)

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't suggest any more, but

- You can use the SQL 2008R2 Express which has a 10GB database limit - unless you're running a hugely busy service I can't imagine you'll hit that. I realise you probably have investment in postgres knowledge, backup systems, etc. though
- At first glance BugTracker.NET does not appear to use any MSSQL-specific code or framework features and so ought to be straight-forward to port
- BugNet does use stored procedures so there's a minor obstacle there
- SlickTicket again doesn't have complex SQL but uses LINQ-to-SQL. There are LINQ-to-PGSQL providers on Google, free or cheap
- Or if you're willing to consider non-.NET you can run e.g. Bugzilla aginst PGSQL on Windows

Comment: Thank you, these are good hints. My primary goal is to answer customer mails, auto categorize mails and use text snippets. Do you know if bugzilla can do that?

Comment: It has rudimentary email support, but actually I don't know how well that's supported on Windows. It's probably more of a bug/issue tracker than a support desk system - perhaps I misunderstood what your focus was, sorry. I don't know the specifics of the others really either - I just looked them up from the other question. Did you mean something more like http://osticket.com/, http://otrs.org/ or http://bestpractical.com/rt ? Annoyingly none of those are both  Windows & PGSQL

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, osticket.com or otrs is something I was looking for. But for windows not linux :)